# Using HttpSessionState in web roles

Tags: azure, session-state, azure-storage, azure-web-roles, azure-caching

I want to be able to use [dedicated or co-located caching](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/) in my Azure web roles.

The problem is that the application I am migrating uses `HttpSessionState` extensively.  I don't want to change all of this code because:

1. This is **time consuming** (especially with testing)
2. I can't enforce developers from **using `HttpSessionState`**
3. I want to avoid **vendor locking** as much as possible

Is there no session provider for dedicated and co-located caching so that I can keep existing code as is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem.  To use the ASP.NET Session State in the dedicated or co-located Azure caching, the following session provider needs to be setup in the web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AFCacheSessionStateProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="AFCacheSessionStateProvider"
         type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache"
         cacheName="default" dataCacheClientName="default"
         applicationName="AFCacheSessionState"
    />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```